# Firebase Authentication Google vs Facebook vs Email pros and cons

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am a newbie to Firebase authentication, please pardon my ignorance.

I am thinking of the pros and cons of adding different types of authentications to my app, instead of adding only one (Google).

Adding all 3 (Google, Facebook and Email) would be more considerate of the user and their email preferences. That's the only reason I can think of, that I would add all 3. Are there any other reasons, if all I need is a user Id, and a way to send the user emails?

What would be the reason to add Facebook if anyone who has an android app has a google account?

And why would I add email authentication? This might discourage the user to enter an email if they have to type it.

I hope this question does not get closed. I am not looking for opinions. I am looking for facts only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really looking for facts, then i'd suggest `Google authentication` via `Email` Auth. But why?

Like you said;

> What would be the reason to add Facebook if anyone ***who has an android
>   app has a google account***?

I've personally seen some users don't even care to sign in on their *Google* account. Meanwhile, there are users who's really working with `Google Play Store` and they care!

So, adding `Google authentication` via `Email` Auth will be a good choice for those who's already signed in and they can logged in very quickly and simply by clicking on `Google Sign in Button` and also, Email Auth for those who's not signed in by Google and love to give the app a shot by their Email.

Adding `FaceBook` or other Authorization method will be a good choice to use on `IOS`. But why? Because in `IOS` there is an `Apple` Id which you can't use it for signing in on applications **like** `Google`. Not sure, i'm not an IOS developer but i don't think Apple would allow such a thing so, those two will be enough for users on Android Platform because Google made it easier to use one account which can be logged in on applications by a `Button`.

Also, nowadays, the best option to develop application or in whatever in our life, *is to make something* **which makes human work quick & easily** like `Kotlin` or this Signed in `Button` which those really are a life and time saver. :)